# Why do I get variable "Node" is not a type name error

Tags: c++, c++14

I have `Node` class which is being inherited by three more classes namely `Leaf`, `Branch`, and `Extension`. I am using boost::variant to store the variant of any of these classes as follows:

```cpp
boost::variant<Node, Branch, Extension, Leaf>;
```

The Node in the above line shows error as follows:

> *variable "Node" is not a type name*

My Class header files are as follows:

> Node class header

```cpp
#include "alias.hpp"

class Node {
    protected:
        buffer_t value_;
        char node_type_;

    public:
        Node();
        Node(const Node &node);
        char GetNodeType();
        void SetNodeType(char  input);
        buffer_t GetValue();
        void SetValue(buffer_t input);
        bufferarray_t Raw();
        buffer_t Serialize();
        buffer_t Hash();
};
```

> Extension class header

```cpp
#include "node.hpp"

class Extension : public Node {
    private:
        nibble_t nibble_;

    public:
        Extension(nibble_t nibble, buffer_t value);
        // ~Extension();

        static nibble_t EncodeKey(const nibble_t& input);
        static nibble_t DecodeKey(const nibble_t& input);

        nibble_t GetKey();
        void SetKey(nibble_t input);
        nibble_t EncodedKey();

        bufferarray_t Raw();
};
```

> Leaf class header

```cpp
#include "node.hpp"

class Leaf : public Node {
    private:
        nibble_t nibbles_;

    public:
        // Leaf();
        // ~Leaf();

        Leaf(nibble_t nibbles, buffer_t value);

        static nibble_t EncodeKey(const nibble_t& input);
        static nibble_t DecodeKey(const nibble_t& input);

        nibble_t GetKey();
        void SetKey(nibble_t input);
        nibble_t EncodedKey();

        bufferarray_t Raw();
};
```

> Branch class header

```cpp
#include <map>

#include "node.hpp"

class Branch : public Node {
    private:
        bufferarray_t branches_;

    public:
        // Branch();
        // ~Branch();

        static Node FromBuffer(const bufferarray_t &input);
        void SetBranch(const int loc, const buffer_t &input);
        buffer_t GetBranch(const int input);
        bufferarray_t GetBranches();
        std::map<int, buffer_t> GetChildren();

        bufferarray_t Raw();
};
```

> The main class definition is as follows:

```cpp
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include "node.hpp"
#include "leaf.hpp"
#include "branch.hpp"
#include "extension.hpp"

// Some other includes

class Trie {
    int main() {
       using node_t = boost::variant<Node, Branch, Extension, Leaf>;
       // Code to test
       return 0;
    }
}
```

> `buffer_t` and `bufferarray_t` are the aliases I created with `using`, and define a vector of `unint64_t` and vector of `buffer_t` respectively. Both are defined in `alias.hpp` file.

What could be the reason for the error?:

> *variable "Node" is not a type name*

**Edit:**
As per @molbdnilo's comment, I assumed that this is one of the weird behavior of the VS Code and not my code. With a little digging, I found wherever I Have `Node`, my editor is considering it as `static NodeType Node`. I don't know from where it is reading this reference, but it is not part of my code.

Comment: One reason could be that there is a variable called "Node" somewhere in `// Some other includes`.

Comment: Do you mean imported libraries like boost? If it is then Should I rename my class or how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: why use boost::variant and not the [std](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) one ?

Comment: try rename your Node class and see if it solev it

Comment: @srahul07 You could put your classes into a namespace. That would still not help if there is a `#define Node <something>` somewhere, though.

Comment: I mean the part that you left out and replaced with a comment. Neither the standard library nor Boost have a variable called "Node", so it must be declared somewhere in your own code.

Comment: @yaodav I am developing for C++14 and std::variant is available in c++17. That is the reason I have to use boost.

Comment: @molbdnilo I reverified in my entire repository, nowhere I have specified variable with name Node. My all variables names are the small case with everyone either start with `_` or end on `_`.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6y9cASzTSgONEOPW) the error. I get redefinition errors because none of the headers have header guards.

Comment: @chris Yes I do have header guards in my file. I have not included those in here just to avoid any clutter.

Comment: I would suggest to remove as many code as possible to find out what generates the error. What if you include just `<boost/variant.hpp>` and `"node.hpp"` and create a variant with `Node` only? Then, you can go deeper to remove the stuff from `node.hpp` etc.

Comment: @srahul07 Only problem is that the issue appears to be somewhere in the parts *not* included.

Comment: do you have header guards? What is "alias.hpp" ? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: In that case, I simply [don't get the error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CxhNjopAMrxPzBmj). There's something different between this link and your code+setup, but everything in the question is in there.

Comment: Is this an actual compilation error, or is it an interactive (and notoriously unreliable) "IntelliSense" message?

Comment: @molbdnilo that is an IntelliSense message given by VS Code.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't complain, there is no error. C++ IntelliSense messages should be treated as hints or guesses, not as facts.

Comment: @dxiv I created a new file and added only boost, node, leaf, branch, and extension headers in include. The error still persists. So it can not be from the part which I have purposely not included in here.

Comment: @molbdnilo as of now, as per your comment and as per my findings, I am assuming it's VS Code acting weird because of which I am seeing that error. If the compiler starts complaining the same then I will get back.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my code. But not the one mentioned in the comments as Node being a variable.

I have an enum defined in a separate header file: `nodetype.hpp`

```cpp
enum NodeType {
    BLANK_NODE = 0,
    BRANCH_NODE = 1,
    EXTENSION_NODE = 2,
    LEAF_NODE = 3
};
```

In the definition of this enum, the semicolon (;) at the end was missing. This enum is imported in one of the util files where the static function was supposed to return the `Node` object. Somehow editor was assuming that `NodeType` and `Node` being related and considering it as

```cpp
static NodeType Node
```

This was the reason of this error/conflict.